# Verb-ing after this phrase or clause "this is my first time"

Tags: syntax, grammar, participles, gerund

Is the verb with '-ing' in the phrase or clause "this is my first time eating this" a gerund or a present participle verb?

I think now I see that "this" probably is or means "this time" or "this time of eating this"

And I think "my first time eating this" might also be or mean "my first time of eating this"

Or some would show "my first time of eating this"
When they would show "my first time eating this"

Or they would replace the phrase "my first time of eating this" with the phrase "my first time eating this".

What might you think?

Comment: "Eating" is certainly a verb .Trad grammar would probably call it a present participle. But modern grammar does not distinguish gerunds and present participles, simply calling both _ing_ forms 'gerund participles'.

Comment: I thought some would think gerund would act as a noun and present participle would act as a verb, an adjective, and an adverb. And I was wondering what is the verb-ing after the phrase "this is my first time".

Comment: And I was wondering what "this" might be within that phrase "this is my first time".

Comment: The _ing_ form can be a gerundial noun, as in "I witnessed the **killing** of the seals", but there is nothing noun-like about "eating" in your example, so it can only be an _ing_ verb.

Comment: I was thinking you could say "eating this is my first time" also so I thought maybe "eating this" would be a gerund too.

Comment: And when I thought someone would show or say "this is my first time eating this", I was thinking "eating this" might be present participle or a gerund or a gerund after that noun "first time".

Comment: And when I was thinking you would say "this is my first time in eating this", I was thinking maybe "eating this" is a gerund or an object of an invisible or unseen preposition.